# Cannot Get Element Behind Another With Z-Index and Declaring Position

Tags: javascript, reactjs, position

I have a div I'm using as header/nav menu. This div has a drop shadow. There is a dropdown menu when you hover over menu item "Configuration". I want this dropdown menu to appear behind the drop shadow. I am using declared positions and z-index for all elements. The dropdown is z-index 99 and header div is index 100. The dropdown will not appear behind the header div.

I am using Gatsby, React, and Radium. The syntax for the styling below is because I'm using a "styles" object in Javascript to apply the styles.

[image: I want the dropdown menu behind the shadow for the element above it.]

```
headerDiv: {
    background: 'white',
    marginBottom: '1.45rem',
    paddingLeft: '10px',
    paddingRight: '10px',
    boxShadow: '0px 6px 6px rgba(0,0,0,0.2)',
    zIndex: '100',
    position: 'relative'
},
dropdownMenu: {
    opacity: '1',
    position: 'absolute',
    top: '95%',
    left: '0',
    zIndex: '99',
    padding: '20px 100px 0px 20px',
    whiteSpace: 'nowrap',
    float: 'left',
    minWidth: '160px',
    margin: '2px 0 0',
    fontSize: '12px',
    textAlign: 'left',
    listStyle: 'none',
    backgroundColor: 'white',
    backgroundClip: 'padding-box',
    boxShadow: '0 6px 12px rgba(0,0,0,0.175)'
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved this with a workaround. I turned off z-index on all elements. Then I created an empty div and gave it the drop shadow. I gave this div a z-index of 99 and the header navigation menu a z-index of 99 (so it appears behind the empty div). Now it works as intended.